# how to compile nats in windows using mingw32?

Tags: cygwin, mingw32, nats.io

**Requirement**
need to generate libnats_static.a using Mingw32-gcc as we are using Mingw32-gcc while linking.

**steps followed**

1. set environment variables to use MinGW32 compilers.
   a.set CC=C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc
   b.set CXX=c:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++
2. cmake .. -DNATS_BUILD_WITH_TLS=OFF -DNATS_BUILD_STREAMING=OFF -G "MinGW Makefiles"
3. make -j20

[cmake successfully created Makefiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPfnn.png)

[compilation failed for make command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DjmR.png)

strong text